# EOF function in c++ |c

Tags: c

for example there is code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>



int intcomp(int *x,int *y) {  return *x-*y;};
int a[10000];
int main(void){
    int i; int n=0;
     while (scanf("%d",&a[n])!=EOF)
          n++;
     qsort(a,n,sizeof(int),intcomp);
      for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
           printf("%d\n",a[i]);
       return 0;


}
```

how tell computer that EOF is reached?

Comment: EOF is a macro and not a function. It normally expands to `-1` and signifies the end of file. You might have to reformulate your question, because it is not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: now that you know the answer please re-edit the question and re-tag it such that it correctly reflects the problem that you had.
It has nothing to do with C or C++ by themselves, more with IO on a terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CTRL+Z combination (or somehow input character with code 26, for example, by pressing ALT+2+6 on additional keyboard)

Answer (score 6):

You mean when entering input interactively?
In a windows shell, ctrl+z on a line on its own. In a *nix shell, ctrl+d. Or just put your input in a file and pipe it, then not only will eof be detected at the appropriate time but also you can automate your testing.